# Qual solução para o erro: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"?

Tags: php, funções

```
   function exemplo() {

    $premio = "Jose ganhou na lotérica 2.000.000,00 mais gastou 
    1.000.000,00 com quanto josé ficou? <br>";

    echo $premio;

    $smtNumero = explode('na lotérica ',$premio);
    $primeiroArray = explode(' mais gastou 1.000', $smtNumero[1]);


    $outroExplode = explode('0 mais gastou ', $premio);
    $segundoF = explode(' com quanto josé ficou?', $outroExplode[1]);

    unset($primeiroArray[1]);
    unset($segundoF[1]);

    $final1 = str_replace (',', '.', $primeiroArray[0]);
    $final2 = str_replace (',', '.', $segundoF[0]);

    $soma = ($final1 - $final2);

    echo $soma;

}

exemplo();
```

Como já mencionado, o código retorna:

> "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Como solucionar este erro?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574465/date-method-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-does-not-want-to-fo  Te ajudaria?

Answer (score 3):

O problema no seu código está ocorrendo devido a variável `$final1` esta recebendo uma string como valor, sendo assim gerando erro na hora do calculo, ela está recebendo esse valor: `2.000.000.00 mais gastou 1.000.000.00 com quanto josé ficou?`, por isso que não funcionaria corretamente,

Eu não entendi bem qual é o objetivo desse código, certamente é para estudos, então eu vou tentar dissecar, a minha resposta, *(que ficou um pouco diferente do seu)*, ok!

```
function exemplo() {

    $premio = "Jose ganhou na lotérica 2.000.000,00 mais gastou 1.000.000,00 com quanto josé ficou? <br>";

    echo($premio);

    $primeiro_valor = substr($premio, 25, 12);
    $segundo_valor = substr($premio, 50, 12);    

    $final1 = str_replace (',', '.', str_replace ('.', '', $primeiro_valor));
    $final2 = str_replace (',', '.', str_replace ('.', '', $segundo_valor));

    $soma = ($final1 - $final2);

    echo $soma;

}

exemplo();
```

Em vez de usar o [`explode();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) optei por utilizar o [`substr();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php), que ao meu ver se enquadra melhor a seu caso, com ela determinei o ponto inicial e a quantidade de caracteres que queria, após isso utilizei o [`str_replace();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) para remover os `"."` e trocar as `","` por `"."`, por que?

Porque no php se usa o ponto, e na sua lógica anterior você só estava trocando as vírgulas por pontos, sendo assim, trocando `1.000.000,00` por `1.000.000.00` isso no php se tornaria basicamente o numeral `1`, pois o numero correto, para o calculo de "um milhão" seria `1000000.00`, após tratar os números eu só fiz uma soma e pronto.